# Joomla 3 and VM password reset redirect to VM register

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I'm using Joomla 3.9.3 with VirtueMart 3.4.2. I have a login page using the standard Joomla login page. When a user clicks on forgot password or forgot username, they are taken to the appropriate page: `/register?view=reset`

[image]

When the email address is entered correctly and captcha solved and you click Submit it doesn't ever send the email to the user, and always redirects to VirtueMart register page: `/shop/user`

[image]

If I click on Forgot Password or Username there on that resulting page, it takes me back to the original url.

I don't have any SEF plugins installed on this site.

Comment: Did you try to verify your mailer to be sure it works ?

Comment: Yes, mailer works as we receive contact form and other forms being emailed, along with Joomla update notifications.

Comment: Login to Admin Panel->Menus-->create Hidden Menu--> Add Layout-->User Edit Profile Layout -->Save (index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit), Can you try this trick. i think  virtuemart component redirects register page ,so same page id used to forget username and password. can you try this.

Comment: Yes, you may post that as the answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Login to Joomla Admin Panel-->Menus-->create Hidden Menu--> Add New Menu Item-->User Edit Profile Layout -->Save (index.php?option=com_users&view=profile&layout=edit)
```

The Problem is there is nothing edit profile page layout .Virtuemart component redirects custom register page , same Itemid taken to forgot username and password.
Above solution will apply automatically problem solved.